# Soft body edges in 2.78a

Tags: rigging, soft-body, collision

I've got a hand model, I've rigged it and now I'm trying to avoid the fingers passing through the hand itself.

I understand that to activate Self Collision in Soft Body I have to activate "Soft Body Edges" but I simply can't find it in Blender 2.78a. When I select the mesh, and go to physics, there is no option for it like in previous versions.

How can I make it?

Thanks!

Edit: I've seen that there might be a problem with the model that I have imported. It's this one http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/81285 and the one used is .x3d. It's a ShapeIndexedFaceSet

[image: Physics menu]

Comment: I added a screenshot of the menu I can access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REWRITTEN ANSWER:** Based on your screenshot, you must be in "Blender Game" mode. The settings you are looking for are available only if you use Cycles or "Blender Render".

Comment: Yes! I've started a new project and saw tha it must be a problem with the model I used. Is  there any condition to add these properties to a mesh?

Comment: You are absolutely right. But for my application I need it on Blender Game. Is there a way to make objects collide  with themselves in blender game engine? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not an expert on the Blender Game, I suggest that you ask a separate specific question (Title: Is there a way to make objects collide with themselves in blender game engine?)(Included tag: game-engine), hopefully somebody can answer it.